# Where to use componentDidUpdate in React

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am a complete newbie in the world of development. I am trying to make an app where we fetch movies. We can search and sort. I don't want to use any plugins as of now.

I have been successful in fetching the data and showing on the grid. Also, searching is working well. But I'm confused if I shall put the searching method in componentDidUpdate React lifecycle hook or not. If it shall be how to do it?

Following is my code:

```
 class App extends Component
{
  constructor(props) 
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    movies: [],
    filteredMovies: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key={0}&language=en-US&page=1')
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        movies : response.data.results,
        filteredMovies : response.data.results
      });
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate()
  {
    ???
  }

 searchBy = (columnSearch, evt) =>
  {
    console.log(columnSearch);
   let movie = this.state.movies;
   if (evt!==undefined && evt.target.value !== undefined && evt.target.value.length > 0) {
    movie = movie.filter(function(i) {
      console.log(columnSearch);
      return i[columnSearch].toString().match( evt.target.value );
    });
  }
  this.setState({
    filteredMovies: movie
  });
  }

  render(){
    const movieRows =( this.state.filteredMovies ===[] || this.state.filteredMovies === undefined)?[]:
    this.state.filteredMovies.map( (rowData, index) => <Movie key ={index} {...rowData} />);

         if(movieRows !== [] && movieRows !== undefined && movieRows !== null)
            return (
              <div className="table">
                <div className="header row">
                  <div className="headercenter">Movie Id
                  <input type="text"  onChange={(evt)=>this.searchBy('id',evt)}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="headercenter"> Title <input type="text" onChange={(evt)=>this.searchBy('title',evt)}/></div>
                  {/* <div className="" onClick={() => this.sortBy('overview')}>OverView</div> */}
                  <div className="headercenter" >Popularity<input type="text" onChange={(evt)=>this.searchBy('popularity',evt)}/></div>
                  <div className="headercenter" >Rating<input type="text"  onChange={(evt)=>this.searchBy('vote_average',evt)}/></div>
                </div>
                <div className="body">
                  {movieRows}
                </div>
              </div>
            ) ;


     
  };
}
 


export default App;

    const movie = (props) => (
    <div className="row">
      <div>{props.id}</div>
      <div>{props.title}</div>
      {/* <div>{props.overview}</div> */}
      <div>{props.popularity}</div>    
      <div>{props.vote_average}</div>    
    </div>
  );

export default movie;
```

Comment: Do you want to do something after your component gets updated? Then use `componentDidUpdate` it'll also give you previous state and props as parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComponentDidUpdate` called when any state update take places inside the component, so you can put search method inside `ComponentDidUpdate` or any method but normally we do things inside `ComponentDidUpdate` which do require some state change and also do not require user input. For any searching you must be requiring user input so I don't recommend that you should put search method inside `ComponentDidUpdate` instead put that method on `onChange` event handler.

**Note:**  `ComponentDidUpdate` if not handled correctly i.e., you update any state inside this without any condition will cause **`Infinite Loop`**

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to call your api in componentDidUpdate method. You should use if condition. Because when your dom is update this method will trigger.

It should look like something like this. I do not know your logic. Please change it for your use case.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
 if(prevProps.movies.lenght != prevState.movies.lenght){
   // call api
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the searching function in `componentDidUpdate`, as it will be automatically called when the `input` field changes. The `componentDidUpdate` function will be called when the component rerenders (for example after state changes).

What you want, is to call the search function when the input in the `input` field changes, for which I would add `keyup` event like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Write in the text field</p>

<input type="text" id="mySelect" />
<p>Down here will show what you write</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('keyup', search)
function search(event) {      
  console.log(event.target.value)
  document.getElementById('demo').innerText = event.target.value
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you this explains well. I will go with on Change event. thanks though.